# Modern Site "Highlighted Content" web Part links not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, css, modern

This seems to be a known issue on Microsoft's website. When a new link is created and a filter is added to the highlighted content web part to pull that link it seems to pull the link in a card layout.

[image]

But upon clicking the link it tries to download the URL file, and not go directly to the link you entered on the link. Very strange.

[image]
[image]
If I go to site pages and click the URL there it goes to the link. 
But I must have a card layout for highlighted content. The cards don't have IDs so I can do any CSS to them. Is there any way to get a link to work like a link is supposed to work?

Comment: what is the file type that is getting referred to in your webpart ?

Comment: I just add a .com link in the links option in the drop down, in the image I just added above.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, after talking with several developers on freelancer, there is no direct way to adjust "Highlighted Content" to make the links work. It is a Microsoft issue; a hard-coded server side facility. The only solution that we can think of is altering the framework web-part or making a custom web-part.

I have yet to find the highlighted content web-part on GitHub but I have a freelancer SharePoint developer working on a solution right now...

more to come in the future....